# Enable/Disable UIButton depends on length of text in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a tableViewController that contains 3 static cells.
Each cell has a UITextField.

I'm trying to calculate the length of text in each textField to enable or disable a button.

To do this I'm using the textField delegate method

`-textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`

but I could not get the right values, For example in the password field I want to enable button when the length exceed 6 letters and disable when the length is less than 6 letters.

Currently I could not get the right length, for example to disable the button in the password field I need to reach the 3 characters otherwise it is not disabled. This is wrong for me because the button must disable when the characters are less than 6.

this is my code can you explain where I'm wrong?

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

     if ([self.passwordTextField.text length] >6 && [self.nameTextField.text length] >2 && [self.emailTextField.text length] >2) [self.stepCompleted setEnabled:YES];

     else if ([self.passwordTextField.text length]  <6 || [self.nameTextField.text length] <2 || [self.emailTextField.text length] <2) [self.stepCompleted setEnabled:NO];


    return YES;
}
```

Comment: you have 3 UITextFields, you need to enable and disable one button using which criteria??? I think your first if statement will never be true because the same UItextField can't be equal to one and equal to another at the same time, if you provide a clear answer to which criteria are you following I can provide an answer for this I think

Comment: @ReinierMelian So ... I'm creating a tableviewcontroller for registering the user for my app. I want this tableView controller to display 3 text fields to enter the user name, email and password. When the keyboard is presented, above it there is a key ("continue to the next step"), this key deletes the tableView controller and presents a new view controller for the next step of recording.

Comment: @ReinierMelian Example:
I need the button to be enabled only if all three textfields are filled in (name at least 2 characters, email at least 2 characters, password at least 6 characters). When one of these textfields contains text with characters lower than desired, the button must be disabled. This must happen even if the user uses the clear button of the textfield or the button deletes the keyboard character

Comment: ok, I will review this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi find the solution for this problem..
If we need to establish a minimum number of characters to be used within multiple `UITextField` we can establish a minimum limit for the textfield that interests us and control the behavior of the remaining textfields within the method...

Es.. we have 3 `UITextField` **name - email - password**

In this example we want a button to be enabled or disabled if the textfields have the minimum characters

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField {
    [button setEnabled:NO];
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    // Otteniamo il numero di caratteri corretti
    NSString *characters = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    int minimumCharacter = 2;
    int minimumCharacterForPassoword = 6;

     // Identifichiamo la textField Generica con la textField che andremo ad utilizzare inoltre aggiungiamo anche il numero di caratteri MINIMI che vogliamo utilizzare per attivare il bottone Continua e quindi consentire all'utente di proseguire con la registrazione, altrimenti, se non tutti i requisiti delle textField vengono soddisfatti disabilitiamo il pulsante Continua fino a quando tutti campi non saranno completati

    // NAME
    if (textField == self.firstNameTextField) {
        if  (characters.length >= minimumCharacter) {
            if ((self.passwordTextField.text.length +1) > minimumCharacterForPassoword && (self.emailTextField.text.length +1) > minimumCharacter) [_stepCompletedButton setEnabled:YES];
            else [_stepCompletedButton setEnabled:NO];
        }
        else [_stepCompletedButton setEnabled:NO];
    }

    // EMAIL
    if (textField == self.emailTextField) {
        if  (characters.length >= minimumCharacter) {
            if ((self.passwordTextField.text.length +1) > minimumCharacterForPassoword && (self.firstNameTextField.text.length +1) > minimumCharacter) [_stepCompletedButton setEnabled:YES];
            else [_stepCompletedButton setEnabled:NO];
        }
        else [_stepCompletedButton setEnabled:NO];
    }

    // PASSWORD
    if (textField == self.passwordTextField) {
        if  (characters.length >= minimumCharacterForPassoword) {
            if ((self.firstNameTextField.text.length +1) > minimumCharacter && (self.emailTextField.text.length +1) > minimumCharacter) [_stepCompletedButton setEnabled:YES];
            else [_stepCompletedButton setEnabled:NO];
        }
        else [_stepCompletedButton setEnabled:NO];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first you need to check that `textfield == self.passwordTextField` or any other textfield contain or not then you apply your condition.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (string==nil || [string isEqualToString:@""] || [string isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] || string.length < 1)
    {
        if([self.nameTextField.text length] < 2 || [self.emailTextField.text length] < 2 || [self.passwordTextField.text length] < 6)
        {
            [self.stepCompleted setEnabled:NO];
        }
    }
    else if(textField == self.passwordTextField && [self.passwordTextField.text length] > 6)
    {
        if([self.nameTextField.text length] > 2 && [self.emailTextField.text length] > 2)
        {
            [self.stepCompleted setEnabled:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.stepCompleted setEnabled:NO];
        }
    }
    else if(textField == self.nameTextField && [self.nameTextField.text length] > 2)
    {
        if([self.passwordTextField.text length] > 6 && [self.emailTextField.text length] > 2)
        {
            [self.stepCompleted setEnabled:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.stepCompleted setEnabled:NO];
        }
    }
    else if(textField == self.emailTextField && [self.emailTextField.text length] > 2)
    {
        if([self.nameTextField.text length] > 2 && [self.passwordTextField.text length] > 6)
        {
            [self.stepCompleted setEnabled:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.stepCompleted setEnabled:NO];
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: you have checked < 6, < 2 and > 6, > 2 condition. what about == 6 ? change according to your requirements

Comment: if I use == 6 all the characters after 6 disable the button ... I need 6 characters to enable the button even if I'm 7 or 8

Comment: I keep having problems when I delete the characters ... it seems I do not respect <6 ... the button is disabled only if it reaches 3 characters ... I do not understand why

Comment: you need to conform the newString because the current textField.text contains the text before adding the new character so you need to check by the new string instead

Comment: @ReinierMelian Hi and thanks for your support .. could you give a little example of your suggestion to understand better?

Comment: @NiravKotecha Thanks .. I try

Comment: @kAiN you want like password have greater than 6 length, name have greater than 2 length and email have greater than 2 length. - if these 3 condition fulfill then button is enabled otherwise not... right ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha exact .. I have expanded my question in the comments under my question

Comment: @NiravKotecha No .. it does not seem to work .. in the passoword field when I arrive at 6 characters the button is enabled but if I delete a character in the passoword field (then back to 5 characters) the button is not disabled

Comment: write else condition at the end and write `[self.stepCompleted setEnabled:NO];` into that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165494/discussion-between-nirav-kotecha-and-kain).

Comment: @NiravKotecha ... im in chat

Comment: unable to connect in chat. updated the else part code in answer

Comment: @kAiN it will be working as per your code but don't know whats problem there! currently with this code what error you facing ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha when I use the backspace button to delete a character the button is not disabled .. even if the remaining characters are less than 6

Comment: @NiravKotecha. I tried your new update but it seems that the space back button does not respond ... When I'm on passoword TextField I have to delete up to 3 characters to disable the button, instead for email and name I have to delete everything to disable the button ... it seems that does not respect the number of characters when I use the space back button to delete

Comment: @kAiN check now

Comment: when you press backspace, it will check that any of the textfield contains lesser length then it will enabled no

Comment: @NiravKotecha no it still does not work ... probably i should use textFieldDidBeginEditing and shouldChangeCharactersInRange to count the characters ... i'm starting to slam my head on the monitor

Comment: @kAiN for temporary, just comment your `textFieldDidBeginEditing` code and try

Comment: i Have Find Solution to this problem... I'm post to share in another answer or Edit my post?

Comment: @kAiN you can put another answer

Comment: @NiravKotecha my answer is very similar to yours ... thanks to you I was able to understand my mistakes and I rebuilt the code that currently does not create me any problem .. thanks again